# Everytime program runs it set values to null

Tags: java, arrays

These are globally declared and initialised arrays which become `null` every time I run the program.

```
public class Inter_pro {

    static String r1[] = new String[11];
    static String r2[] = new String[11];
    static String r3[] = new String[11];
    static String r4[] = new String[11];
    static String r5[] = new String[11];
    String room = null;
```

This function when called it changes the appropriate array values from `null` to 'res'. But it happens once and is forgotten after program termination.

```
String room_allot(int from, int to) {
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i4 = 0, i5 = 0;
    int a = (to - from) + 1;

    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        System.out.println(r1[i]);
    }

    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {

        if (r1[i] == null)
            i1++;
        else if (r2[i] == null)
            i2++;
        else if (r3[i] == null)
            i3++;
        else if (r4[i] == null)
            i4++;
        else if (r5[i] == null)
            i5++;
    }

    if (i1 == ((to - from) + 1)) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            r1[i] = new String("hello");
        }
        room = "room1";
        System.out.println("in loop1 room:" + room);
    }

    if (i2 == ((to - from) + 1)) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            r1[i] = "res";
        }
        room = "room2";

    }
    if (i3 == ((to - from) + 1)) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            r1[i] = "res";
        }
        room = "room3";

    }
    if (i4 == ((to - from) + 1)) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            r1[i] = "res";
        }
        room = "room4";
    }
    if (i5 == ((to - from) + 1)) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            r1[i] = "res";
        }
        room = "room5";

    }
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        System.out.println("ye baad me:" + r1[i] + "\n");
        // r1[i]="res";
    }

    System.out.println(room);

    return room;
}
```

sorry for long code no other way to explain you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    Inter_pro a1 = new Inter_pro();

    System.out.println("Enter the day from(between 1 to 12):\n");
    a1.setFrom(s.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter the day to(between 1 to 12):\n");
    a1.setTo(s.nextInt());

    String room = a1.room_allot(a1.getFrom(), a1.getTo());
    System.out.println("room alloted:" + room);

    main(null);
}
```

I want you guys to help me to get rid of this logical error.
I want to remember my arrays that old values which each time program calling makes changes to them.

What should I do?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a database? Also please have a look about naming conventions and code-style guidelines for Java.

Comment: Either you need a file to store your values or a database.

Comment: my restriction is to not use any database or file. @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: You have to store it somewhere. Expecting the program to "remember" arrays itself is like expecting to replace a dead pet and have the new pet know the tricks you taught it.

Comment: Mmm... Static variables as persistent data storage... Between executions... Mmmm...

Comment: @Aditya Why there are 5 static arrays in your program?

Comment: actually each array is analogue of a room. r1-room1,r2-room2. @Rajesh

Comment: @AdityaSoni As [Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna) said, to keep the data between executions, you have to store it somewhere. See your JVM as a computer: the stack and heap (where you store all current execution data) are RAM. Stop your computer and all is lost, you won't have it next time you boot your computer up. To do that, you need to store to hard drive, and this means to the filesystem. That can be a file, a database, the registry (on Windows, but polluting the registry is always a bad idea). It _has_ to be somewhere _outside_ your JVM.

Comment: @AdityaSoni Out of curiousity (and hoping to understand your problem better and maybe come up with something): why is the use of a file or a database forbidden? I can understand you may not have access to a database but surely you have access to a filesystem. What is the reason why you should not use it?

Comment: actually i am calling main(null) again and  again ,during this process my arrays will remember this values .. and get exit only when all arrays get filled completely.(btw my problem is solved thanks all).

Comment: @AdityaSoni Glad you found a solution! Maybe you could share by posting an answer explaining what you did so that it could benefit future users. (The void of unanswered questions leaves me profoundly disturbed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `main(null);` which makes your program to continue. I don't see it terminates ever in normal flow.

See below code might be what you are trying to achieve:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterPro {

    private int to = 0;
    private int from = 0;

    static String rooms[] = new String[12];
    private String room = null;
    private String delim = ", ";

    String room_allot(int from, int to) {

        for (int i = from - 1; i <= to - 1; i++) {

            if (rooms[i] == null) {

                rooms[i] = new String("Res");

                if (room == null)
                    room = "room" + (i + 1);
                else
                    room += delim + "room" + (i + 1);
            }
        }

        return room;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            InterPro ip = new InterPro();

            System.out.println("Enter the day from(between 1 to 12):\n");
            ip.setFrom(s.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Enter the day to(between 1 to 12):\n");
            ip.setTo(s.nextInt());

            String roomAlloted = ip.room_allot(ip.getFrom(), ip.getTo());

            if (roomAlloted == null)
                System.out
                        .println("Requested rooms are reserved. Enter other choice");
            else
                System.out.println("rooms alloted:" + roomAlloted);

            if (!ip.checkRoomAvailability()) {

                System.out.println("No rooms available!!!"
                        + " Program terminating... ");

                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        main(null);
    }

    boolean checkRoomAvailability() {
        for (String string : rooms)
            if (string == null)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    private int getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    private int getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    private void setTo(int to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    private void setFrom(int from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @Rajesh.. thanks for the code,it works also but not fulfilled my actual requirement of application.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a "logical error".

Let us see what you are doing:

```
public class Inter_pro {
    static String r1[] = new String[11];
    static String r2[] = new String[11];
    // ...
}
```

This means `r1`, `r2` and the others will be initialized once when the class `Inter_pro` is loaded and will be shared between all instances of this class.

**But** it does not mean this data has to be saved between runs. The class is loaded each time you start your program.

If you need to keep data between runs, you need to manually store them. You can search for different solutions and find which one is most adapted to your case:

- Use a database.
- Use a [properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).
- Use the [Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html).

In any case, you will need to perform manual loading and storing to your data repository:

- On program start, search if the repository contains data and load it to your `Inter_pro` class if it does.
- Before program exits (or each time a field is updated), store the new state to your data repository.

Once you have made your mind, you should try to write it on your own. If you fail to, you may ask a new question with your attempt, failures and so.

Keep in mind the 'write my code' questions are not the purpose of StackOverflow and you will be downvoted unless you can prove you tried (I mean, seriously tried).

---

<sub>Minor notes: Java recommends CamelCase notation (your class should rather be called `InterPro`). Applying this and most of all proper formatting would make collaborating easier.</sub>

Comment: i am not asking to 'write my code'. code is already written by me, problem is i am trying to make my array remeber previous values.

Comment: @AdityaSoni Your question was downvoted because you seem to considered established and known behaviour as an error. This is often perceived as a lack of research. Doing what you want will require to write code. I proposed you some clues (though my list is far from exhaustive) and I hope this will help you, but I can hardly go further.

Comment: I do research upto 99.9% by myself, and if its not worked then i beg for the help.(your system didnt identified it)